# "Going to school" vs "going to his/her school"

Tags: phrase-choice

Are the two phrases the same? Or they differ in meaning?

Example sentence:

> I suspect she isn't going to school.
>
> I suspect she isn't going to her school.

What I want to convey is this: She just told me she's heading to (her) school. But I think she isn't.

Comment: are you talking about a student or a teacher?

Comment: 'Going to her school' is ambiguous. It can also mean that she *owns* the school.

Comment: School alone is a generalization of a location. Her school denotes a specific locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They convey a difference in that in the first example you suspect she isn't going to school (**her school** is implied). In the second example you clarify you suspect she isn't going to her school. Implying you suspect she might be going to (a) school. Just not hers.

My answer of course is the literal dissection of the sentences. Either are acceptable in everyday usage. It's where your emphasis is, her school, or any school.